# Is the high dimensionality of input vectors a problem for a radial basis function neural network?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, classification, transfer-learning

I have a dataset A of videos. I've extracted the feature vector of each video (with a convolutional neural network, via transfer learning) creating a dataset B. Now, every vector of the dataset B has a high dimension (about 16000), and I would like to classify these vectors using an RBF-ANN (there are only 2 possible classes).

Is the high dimensionality of input vectors a problem for a radial basis function ANN? If yes, is there any way to deal with it?